# Why transaction can't commit in a self-invoked ejb method with @REQUIRES_NEW Annotation

Tags: jpa, ejb, java-ee-6, jta, jboss6.x

First I want to explain my self-invoked ejb method in this situation. I have a stateful session bean with a method which starts a new transaction (Annotated by `@REQUIRES_NEW`). To invoke this method inside the bean itself and make the annotation effective, I use `SessionContext#getBusinessObject()` to achieve the effect of `@EJB` (**`@EJB` here causes stackoverflow?!**). My code is shown below:

```
@Stateful
@Local
public class TransactionTest implements ITransactionTest {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="Table",Type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)

  private EntityManager manager;

  @Resource
  SessionContext sc;

  ITransactionTest me;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    me = this.sc.getBusinessObject(ITransactionTest.class);
  }

  public void generateRecord(int i) throws RuntimeException{
    Record record = new Record();
    record.setId(i+"");
    record.status(1);
    manager.persist(record);
    manager.flush();  //If not flush, result is correct. Why? 
    me.updateRecord(i);
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void updateRecord(int i) throws RuntimeException{
    try {
      Record record = manager.find(Record.class, i+"");
      record.setStatus(2);
      manager.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }
}
```

While,`generateRecord()` runs properly. The console shows it executes 'insert' and 'update' HQL without any exception (I use Hibernate as JPA provider). However, the 'update' result doesn't appear in the database. **Why? Does `updateRecord()` commit correctly?**

Also, I try it in two altenative ways: First is invoking `generateRecord()` (it will no longer invoke `updateRecord()`) and `updateRecord()` consecutively in another bean. It can give me the right result.

The second is removing the first `flush()`. Then both 'insert' and 'update' HQL will be executed at the second `flush()`. This method can also produce right result.

My program is running under JBOSS 6.1.0-Final and database is Oracle.

Best Regards,

Kajelas

Comment: Your setup seems very strange to me - why are you doing all this stuff with the SessionContext? 1st, if you're using JEE6, there's no use for the interface of a local EJB. 2nd, each call to an EJB is automatically wrapped in a transaction and will be committed if finished successfully. 3rd, if you work with managed entities, there's no need to do a flush, it will be visible to your EJB since all methods work with the same entity manager and to others after finishing the call. Finally, you should always able to call an update method from the create method without any boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you for your advices! First, Do you mean I should use JNDI lookup method to get a local EJB? Does it make any performance difference from my code? For your other points, I understand what you say and I did as you suggest at the very beginning. However, it didn't work. e.g. my ejb method was finished successfully but nothing happened to my database. So I modify my code as what I show. Consequently, I hope to know is there anything missing or totally wrong in my code?

Comment: No, you don't need to fiddle with JNDI - in JEE6 you have EJB 3.1 and there you don't need to have any interface for your EJB, all public methods are automatically accessible by other local EJBs. If you need to obtain a reference to another EJB, just annotate @Inject and you're done. Concerning performance, that way you don't have to go through the network stack in order to come back to your own application. -- But in your case, all this is not needed, since you work within one EJB, so why at all do you try to get a reference to yourself? You can just use your own objects.

Comment: Ah, I must say I need self-reference just because I hope to use `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation to start a new transaction. It can't work if the method isn't called as an EJB method.